# Error when Trying to pass Variable to Next View Controller

Tags: ios, swift

My segue is called "SegueAfterJoin", and the view controller that it goes to is called `SignUpViewController3` - I have already identified this. Xcode says "use of undeclared type `SignUpViewController3`".

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue!, sender: AnyObject!) {
    if (segue.identifier == "SegueAfterJoin") {
        var svc = segue.nextViewController as SignUpViewController3;

        svc.toPass = self.passwordtextfield.text
        svc.toPass = self.usernametextfield.text
        svc.toPass = self.emailtextfield.text


    }
}
```

Comment: What is the type of your `nextViewController`?  Xcode is saying there isn't a class called `SignUpViewController3` in your project.

Comment: dont' you want to use destinationViewController ?

Comment: @JAL my destinationViewController is assigned to class SignUpViewController3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue!, sender: AnyObject!) {
    if (segue.identifier == "SegueAfterJoin") {
        if let svc = segue.destinationViewController as? SignUpViewController3 {
            svc.toPass = self.passwordtextfield.text
            svc.toPass = self.usernametextfield.text
            svc.toPass = self.emailtextfield.text
        }
    }
}
```

Make sure that the SignUpViewController3 source file is present in your project and included in the target.

Comment: Thanks How do I "include it in the target"?

Comment: You should set the checkbox for the target in the file's info window that appears on the right side of the project window.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code you should use

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {
    if (segue.identifier == "SegueAfterJoin") {
        var svc = segue.destinationViewController as! SignUpViewController3;

        svc.toPass = self.passwordtextfield.text
        svc.toPass = self.usernametextfield.text
        svc.toPass = self.emailtextfield.text


    }
}
```